# SSSD with AD: How can I ensure AD groups not missing when ldap_id_mapping = False?

Tags: ldap, active-directory, domain-server, sssd

Why does altering `ldap_id_mapping` present different group memberships on the same AD user?

I was hoping to have my `UID/GID` be the same as AD with IDMU: [SSSD with AD: use UID/GID specified on domain server instead of something random?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300389/sssd-with-ad-use-uid-gid-specified-on-domain-server-instead-of-something-random#1300389)

I have achieved this by setting `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` `ldap_id_mapping = False`, but now some of my AD groups are 'missing'.

The previous AD user with `ldap_id_mapping = True` reflected all the AD groups of which the user is a member, while the `ldap_id_mapping = False` user does not.

e.g:

```
% sssd --version
2.3.1

% cat /etc/sssd/sssd.conf | grep id_mapping

ldap_id_mapping = True

% su auser@mydomain.space                                        
Password: 
auser@mydomain.space@myhostname:~/$ id

uid=397401108(auser@mydomain.space)
gid=397400512(domain admins@mydomain.space)
groups=397400512(domain admins@mydomain.space),
397400513(domain users@mydomain.space),
397400518(schema admins@mydomain.space),
397400519(enterprise admins@mydomain.space),
397400572(denied rodc password replication group@mydomain.space),
397401109(sudoers@mydomain.space),
397401112(vcsa administrators@mydomain.space),
397404603(libvirt@mydomain.space),
397407607(jumpcloud@mydomain.space)

% exit
```

Above, you can see there are several AD-specific groups represented

```
% su -

# sed -i 's/ldap_id_mapping = True/ldap_id_mapping = False/g' /etc/sssd/sssd.conf 

# cat /etc/sssd/sssd.conf | grep id_mapping

ldap_id_mapping = False

# exit

% su auser@mydomain.space                                        
Password: 
auser@mydomain.space@myhostname:~/$ id

uid=10000(auser)
gid=10001(administrators)
groups=10001(administrators),
3109(sudoers@mydomain.space),
10000(domain users@mydomain.space)
```

Now you can see the AD-specific groups are not represented on the SSSD client.

Anyone have an idea why all these groups are not present on my domain user after changing this setting?  Aren't all existing AD groups and users mapped to an ldap equivalent?

Is it because the groups presented when `ldap_id_mapping = True` are not being mapped with `ldap_id_mapping = False`?

How can I ensure these groups are not 'missing' on SSSD clients when `ldap_id_mapping = False`?

Comment: My first guess would be those missing groups don't have the LDAP attributes needed by SSSD.  I'd suggest adding to your `sssd.conf` in the **mydomain.space** section a value of `debug_level = 9`.  There will be a lot of output to go through, but the logs will show all the LDAP queries being made and hopefully why the groups are omitted.